# Visual Studio not pull any objects from Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I have all the classes and everything else but I could not get the any objects in MS VS Code. What am I doing wrong? 
I did use SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest but that did not help either.

This is what I have tried so far. Where am I making the mistake?

```
    <types>
        <member>Account</members>
        <name>StandardObject</name>
    </types>


    <types>
    <member>*</members>
    <name>StandardObject</name>
   </types>


   <types>
        <member>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in your manifest? What objects are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: I am trying to pull all the objects. In the manifest, it shows Apex Class, Apex Component, Apex Page, Trigger, Static resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include custom objects in your manifest in order to retrieve them.

Add an entry like

```
<types>
     <members>*</members>
     <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

to your `package.xml` to retrieve all custom objects.

Note that this will not retrieve customizations to standard objects. You'll need to add an individual `<members>` line for each standard object you wish to retrieve.

#### Edit

There is no such entity as `StandardObject`. Customizations to standard objects are retrieved with the `CustomObject` entity, but *you must specify each one individually by name*. The wildcard `*` is not supported for retrieval of standard object customizations.

For example:

```
<types>
     <members>*</members>
     <members>Account</members>
     <members>Opportunity</members>
     <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Thank you, David. I will try and report back

Comment: Hi David, I tried multiple things but nothing seems to working .. would you know why?

Comment: @mike You'd need to edit your post with all of the details of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks David. That worked!. I think the problem was that I was not saving after making changes.